# Fixed effect panel regression gives coefficients for each year

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, panel-data, linearmodels

I am trying to use Entity fixed panel regression for my data set. I have cross sectional data for each county in the US and for 1971 to 2020 (yearly). I have two indices: `STCTID` which is county ID and `Date`. Below is how my dataset looks like:

[image]

Apart from the date index, I have `Year` column as an explanatory variable too. Below is my code for fitting panel regression using `linearmodels`, I keep the entity fixed effects but no time effect:

```
from linearmodels import PanelOLS

formula1 = "Yld ~ Year + Prec + GDD + KDD + VPD + Irg +Irg*Prec 
+ Irg*GDD + Irg*KDD + Irg*VPD + EntityEffects"

mod = PanelOLS.from_formula(formula1, data=df_all_semw)
panelOLS_res = mod.fit(cov_type="clustered", cluster_entity=True)
```

Printing `panelOLS_res` gives the details about the regression coefficients and information. What I found strange is that the model gives regression coefficients for each year in `Year` variable. See below:

```
    Parameter   Std. Err.   T-stat  P-value Lower CI    Upper CI

    GDD 0.0560  0.0028  20.148  0.0000  0.0505  0.0614
    Irg 0.0008  0.0002  4.2808  0.0000  0.0005  0.0012
    KDD -0.1646 0.0058  -28.269 0.0000  -0.1760 -0.1532
    Prec    -0.0006 0.0016  -0.3816 0.7028  -0.0037 0.0025
    VPD -5.4312 1.4328  -3.7907 0.0002  -8.2395 -2.6228
    Year[T.1971]    14.009  4.7535  2.9471  0.0032  4.6917  23.326
    Year[T.1972]    20.115  4.9404  4.0715  0.0000  10.432  29.799
    Year[T.1973]    20.867  5.0448  4.1364  0.0000  10.979  30.756
    Year[T.1974]    6.5041  4.7447  1.3708  0.1704  -2.7959 15.804
    Year[T.1975]    8.6791  5.0379  1.7228  0.0849  -1.1955 18.554
    Year[T.1976]    14.602  4.8642  3.0020  0.0027  5.0683  24.136
    Year[T.1977]    15.879  5.1194  3.1018  0.0019  5.8451  25.914
    Year[T.1978]    28.605  4.9551  5.7728  0.0000  18.893  38.317
   ... and so on
```

I found this is because the datatype of `Year` is `object`, when I change it to `int`, I dont get these coefficients for each year, but then the R-squared drops down. Could somebody explain me the reason behind this? Is there any problem with the current model (with each year getting coefficient), if no, how can I explain it to others?